# Laravel notification: Check if the notification is sent

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-notification

Am Working on laravel 9. I send notification using the notifiable trait and I wish to make some action only if the notification is.

How can I perform this!

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think You can check using `Notification::failure()`

```
if (Notification::failure() > 0){
  //your required function;
}
```